# htaccess to redirect non-www to www and http to https

Tags: .htaccess

I have something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

It works fine, redirects all http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com. But now I want it to redirect all example.com to https://www.example.com. I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

And it failed. What should I add ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do both redirections in a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: It works fine on my Apache. Make sure this is very first rule and you completely clear your browser cache.

Comment: i tried on different browser and mobile web browser also. Btw, it does not matter what server i use, right ? I use openshift to host my application.

Comment: This works on my Apache 2.4. What is the full URL you are entering in browser?

Comment: i used example.com when I tried you solution, it does not redirect me. And also, all the route in the app were redirect and return no content.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, same rule works fine. Can you show your `VirtualHost` entries in question?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code in your .htaccess file automatically redirects visitors to the HTTPS version of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or help with this site. Recently i get same issue than they fix this issue.
https://www.themeconfig.com/wordpress-basic-services/

Comment: thank! but i already redirect to https, now i want to redirect non-www to www also